# NLTK Mutli word tokenzier works is case sensitive. I want to work for both upper and lower case

Tags: python, nlp, tokenize

NLTK Mutli word tokenzier works is case sensitive. I want to work for both upper and lower case

```
tk.add_mwe(('The', 'questions'))
```

works for the word **The questions**

But fails for the word **the questions**

Plz give a solution or an alternate

Comment: convert all to `lower()` or `upper()` and work only with one size.

Comment: if i do case conversion i  loose the original word

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the excellent [FlashText](https://github.com/vi3k6i5/flashtext) library. 
It can locate your multi-word expressions (MWEs) in a case insensitive fashion.
Once you have extracted those MWEs from your document, you can add them to the MWETokenizer (with the same capitalization as they have in the document). Then tokenize your document.

The following code illustrates this process:

```
from flashtext import KeywordProcessor

keyword_processor = KeywordProcessor()

keyword_processor.add_keyword('The questions')
keyword_processor.add_keyword('Starting Point')

sentence = "the questions are the starting point"
keywords_found = keyword_processor.extract_keywords(sentence, span_info=True)

keywords_found

from nltk.tokenize import MWETokenizer
tokenizer = MWETokenizer()
for a in keywords_found:
    tokenizer.add_mwe(sentence[a[1]: a[2]].split())

tokenizer.tokenize(sentence.split())
```

ouput:

> ['The_questions', 'are', 'the', 'starting_point']